# Task with OnFaulted continuation throws TaskCancelledException on WaitAll

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Ran into this today.
Can anyone explain why this throws a TaskCancelledException ?

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Task t = Task.Run(() => { }).ContinueWith((task) => { }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    tasks[i] = t;
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

If I specify NotOnFaulted instead - it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Task t` variable is return value of `ContinueWith` which will be executed only when there is an `Exception (OnlyOnFaulted)` thrown. Otherwise, the continuation will be canceled.

So in this case it will be canceled; not executed. Hence waiting on it throws `TaskCancelledException`

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Task t = Task.Run(() =>
    {

    });
    t.ContinueWith((task) => 
    { 

    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    tasks[i] = t;//t is from Task.Run not ContinueWith
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Did you mean this?

Comment: Ah, how did I overlook it.. Thanks!